# Error while disable sandbox property for word automation services in sharepoint2010

Tags: word-automation

i have execute below script for disabling sandbox property for word automation services.

```
$sp = Get-SPServiceApplication | where {$_.TypeName.Equals("Word Automation Services")}
$sp.DisableSandbox = $true
$sp.Update()
```

but getting below exception..

[image]

How to disable sandbox property ?

because using Word Automation Services not generating pdf documents from word documents.

So i need to disable sandbox property..

Any Solutions...?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have Word Automation Services application is created in your farm.
you can create using steps in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557330(v=office.14).aspx

I could reproduce the error as below,on Line 1 $sp variable has null as the where didn't return any value

line 1: `$sp = Get-SPServiceApplication | where {$_.TypeName.Equals("Word Automation 
Services1xyz")}`

line 2: `$sp.DisableSandbox = $true`

line 3: `$sp.Update()`

Error details

> Property 'DisableSandbox' cannot be found on this object; make sure it
>   exists and is settable. At line:2 char:5
>   + $sp. <<<< DisableSandbox = $true
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DisableSandbox:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:3 char:11
>   + $sp.Update <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Update:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Hope this helps