# SharePoint 2013 Word Automaion Service Error 65543

Tags: 2013, pdf, word-automation

I'm using Word Automation Service for converting Word to PDF files in SharePoint 2013.

Getting error code 65543: "The file could not be converted; it may be corrupt or otherwise invalid (the conversion process failed). Please try opening the file in Microsoft Word, resaving it, and then resubmitting the file for conversion. If this does not resolve the issue, contact your system administrator."

As a solution for this error in SharePoint 2010 I've found the Powershell script for disabling the sandbox. In SharePoint 2013 this script doesn't work anymore. Script provided below.

$sp = Get-SPServiceApplication | where {$_.TypeName.Equals("Word Automation Services")}
$sp.DisableSandbox = $true
$sp.Update()

I've also created and configured Word Automation Service as described in MSDN articles.

Ideas how to fix this? Anybody?
Thanks!

Comment: Check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59619/error-while-disable-sandbox-property-for-word-automation-services-in-sharepoint2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my Domain Controller was in my dev environment. I have created new environment for Domain Controller and reinstalled my dev environment for SharePoint and SQL.
This fixed my issue, now the Word Automation Process is working.

Comment: Why so? I mean is that really can be the reason? i'm facing same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Word Automation Services can fail for several reasons. When the service is healthy, the most common reasons for a failed conversion are as follows:

- The file type is intentionally blocked by the administrator (using
  the SharePoint Server 2010 Central Administration web site).
- The file is password-protected or requires Information Rights
  Management (IRM) permissions in order to be viewed.
- The file type is not supported by this version of Word Automation
  Services. The service does not support converting documents created
  by using Preview versions of Word before Word 2010.
- The user who submitted the conversion job had insufficient
  permissions to read or write to the source or destination location of
  the conversion.

Also check: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29f11542-b2b5-4e08-94fd-589b993f3fd0/error-code-65543-the-file-could-not-be-converted-it-may-be-corrupt-or-otherwise-invalid-the?forum=sharepointdevelopment